Can't RDP into Ubuntu24.04 as other users
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 on an Arm SBC.  The image is (ubuntu-24.04-gnome-linux-5.15-fenix-1.6.9)  I installed gnome-remote-desktop and turned on the RDP in the settings.  I can log in as the original user named Khadas, but I made another user and I can't RDP in as that guy.
What settings might be missing from other added users that might break RDP?
The net effect is as follows.  The original user that came with the flashed image was named Kahdas (Vim3 SBC arm board).  I logged in as this user and installed gnome-remote-desktop.  Then I tried RDP from a different box running LinuxMint box and it RDP into the Khadas account fine.  I then added another user named Sam and reset the Vim3 SBC.  I then tried to RDP into the Vim3, where I then saw the login screen and got to choose the user (Khadas or Sam).  When I select Sam, I am asked to login and it looks like it starts a normal login process but the screen stays black forever.  I can break the connection and go through it again and login as the original Khadas user and it goes to his desktop just fine.
It's the other users that are missing something that makes the login effort result in a black screen in the RDP window.
Let me know if you know of any other settings that need to be added per user to get the other users to allow RDP correctly.

Please be precise with details; Ubuntu 24?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 24 install?  (24.04 & 24 are different products; the year or 24 representing the snap only version).  You then switch to talking about a non-Ubuntu but Linux Mint install; you're on the incorrect site for Linux Mint support as its not a Ubuntu product; maybe try SE Unix & Linux if you wish support on Linux systems; this is Ubuntu only (if your mention of Linux Mint was example; it's unclear & not-useful anyway as no software stack details were provided; Linux Mint have different product/defaults & you didn't specify)

I install Ubuntu24.04 to the remote SBC.  I attempted RDP from a laptop running LinuxMint.  But nevermind the LinuxMint part, it's the server from the Ubuntu24.04 that I believe needs the fix.

Correct your question then, as it states 24 and not 24.04 (Ubuntu Core 24 being the snap only version released two months after 24.04; details matter).  This is a Q&A site, and answers will be to your question.  Comments are intended to be comments by readers to the OP or Original Poster, they'll get removed once addressed in the question; ie. when question is clear, as clear questions get best/fastest answers usually

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   You're NOT using a Ubuntu product your image shows, but a Ubuntu based product which is not supported here

It was 24.04.  Is that a version of Ubuntu?   -> ubuntu-24.04-gnome-linux-5.15-fenix-1.6.9)

Many Ubuntu based systems use 24.04, as 24.04 represents 2024-April which is a calendar representation only... Pop OS 24.04 for example is not a Ubuntu product; that isn't found/downloaded from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ (or authorized mirror) where all Ubuntu images comes from.

I see, I'll stick to Mint from now on.  :\  Thanks for the welcome guy.
